# Прямая речь в тексте

Tags: прямая-речь, диалог, пунктуация

Как правильно оформить диалог в этом абзаце? Подскажите, пожалуйста?

Привезли на Курскую АЭС (номер энергоблока не помню, да он к делу и не относится). – «Давайте-ка ещё у нас на стендах проверим». Проверили. Получили разрешение на установку в реактор.
Тихонько опускаем в реактор первый ИМ. «Всё полностью!» Всё да не всё! На несколько миллиметров фланец ИМ  не дошел до фланца установочной трубы. – «Что будем делать, товарищ ученый?»
- «Не знаю. А что Вы обычно делаете в таких случаях?» 
- «Сейчас покажем». Обнимаются, дружелюбно говоря, два «бугая» и вместе прыгают на крышку привода. Сердце ёкает. Привод на месте. Второй – четвертый вошли без прыгания. Вот что значит, установка привода сверху.

**Обновление**

«Давайте-ка ещё у нас на стендах проверим». Проверили. Получили разрешение на установку в реактор. Тихонько опускаем в реактор первый ИМ. «Всё полностью!» Всё да не всё! На несколько миллиметров фланец ИМ не дошел до фланца установочной трубы. – «Что будем делать, товарищ ученый?» – «Не знаю. А что Вы обычно делаете в таких случаях?» – «Сейчас покажем», – обнимаются, дружелюбно говоря, два «бугая» и вместе прыгают на крышку привода. Сердце ёкает. Привод на месте. Второй – четвертый вошли без прыгания. Вот что значит, установка привода сверху.

Так правильно? Или тире перед "Что будем делать..." лишнее?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Привезли на Курскую АЭС (номер энергоблока не помню, да он к делу и не относится). «Давайте-ка ещё у нас на стендах проверим». Проверили. Получили разрешение на установку в реактор. Тихонько опускаем в реактор первый ИМ. «Всё, полностью!» Всё, да не всё! На несколько миллиметров фланец ИМ не дошел до фланца установочной трубы.  «Что будем делать, товарищ ученый?» - «Не знаю. А что Вы обычно делаете в таких случаях?» - «Сейчас покажем». Обнимаются, дружелюбно говоря, два «бугая» и вместе прыгают на крышку привода. Сердце ёкает. Привод на месте. Второй – четвертый вошли без прыгания. Вот что значит установка привода сверху.

Тире разделяет реплики, чтобы указать на принадлежность разным участникам диалога. Всё, да не всё! - видимо, всё-таки не фразеологизм, запятая нужна. А во фразе «Всё полностью!» нет запятой после "всё"? Воспринимается с запятой. Вот что значит установка = вот что означает, запятой нет.

Answer (score 0):

Если вначале идет текст от автора (вводная часть, описание и т. д.), а потом предложение, вводящее прямую речь, то это предложение обычно начинается с ***абзаца.***
Если реплики следуют в ***подбор***, без указания, кому они принадлежат, то каждая из них заключается в кавычки и отделяется от соседней ***тире:***
***Привезли на Курскую АЭС (номер энергоблока не помню, да он к делу и не относится).
   "Давайте-ка ещё у нас на стендах проверим". - "Проверили". - "Получили разрешение на установку в реактор''. Тихонько опускаем в реактор первый ИМ. Всё полностью!" - ''Всё да не всё! На несколько миллиметров фланец ИМ не дошел до фланца установочной трубы". -  "Что будем делать, товарищ ученый?" - "Не знаю". -  "А что Вы обычно делаете в таких случаях?" - "Сейчас покажем".
  Обнимаются, дружелюбно говоря, два «бугая и вместе прыгают на крышку привода. Сердце ёкает. Привод на месте. Второй, четвертый вошли без прыгания. Вот что значит, установка привода сверху. 
Насчет последнего предложения:*** "Сердце ёкает...". Если это предложение входит в прямую речь, его следует тоже выделить кавычками. Мне кажется, это слова автора, поэтому не выделяю кавычками.

**Обновление**

Перед первой репликой тире не ставится. У вас прямая речь не заключена в кавычки. Обратите внимание, сколько лишних символов в вашем тексте. Уберите лишние символы и заключите в кавычки то, что Вы считаете прямой речью. А потом проверим. См. у Розенталя. Стр. 308, & 58, стр. 310, & 53.

[[@Alenka](/users/4012/alenka)](/users/4012/alenka), если перед "Что будем делать..." идут слова автора, то тире нужно. Тире также нужно, если перед "Что будем делать..." идет другая реплика.

Answer (score 0):

Тире перед "Что будем делать" лишнее.